# Boolean value not getting mapped properly in Hibernate with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, boolean

I am trying to map the result of an exists query (which returns TRUE/FALSE) from a MySQL database to a POJO via *resultSetTransformer*. I would hope the result of this exists query can get mapped to a boolean but it does not and throws the below error:

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred while calling setter of TestBean.value

The cause of this exception is shown as:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

My sample class:

```
public class TestHibernate {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        try {
            Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().createSQLQuery(
                "SELECT " +
                "EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE id = 3) AS value"
            );

            query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TestBean.class));
            List<TestBean> beanList = (List<TestBean>) query.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

The POJO:

```
public class TestBean {

    private boolean value;

    public boolean isValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug with Hibernate or MySQL JDBC Driver?

Hibernate version: 3.2.6GA
MySQL JDBC Driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.2

Comment: You are going about this incorrrctly.  Do you want a raw query?  Do you want to return an entity or just a list of objects?  There are too many problems to motivate me to give an answer, but have a look at a tutorial [like this one](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/).

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong in accepting a single entity returned by the raw query wrapped in a list

Comment: We can do it even if TestBean is not related  to a table - checkout :Transformers.aliasToBean" method

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has a built-in "yes_no" type that would do what you want. It maps to a CHAR(1) column in the database.

Basic mapping:

```
<property name="some_flag" type="yes_no"/>
```

Annotation mapping (Hibernate extensions):

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
public boolean getFlag();
```

Comment: I am more concerned in why Should I be doing this... Shouldn't hibernate determine the correct type and map it properly as it does for other types? Will wait to see if I get any thoughts on that..

Comment: This too gives the same error.Moreover I am not sure if the result of exists query is a char(1) column..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by the case mapping of the selected column, q.v. my solution below.  I also parametrized your `WHERE` clause to avoid SQL injection.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select exists(select * from A where id = :id) as value");
    .setParameter("id", "3");
    .addScalar("value")
    .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(TestBean.class))

List result = query.list();
TestBean theBean = (TestBean)result.get(0);
```

Comment: Does not work .. Also i think its not a casing issue because the exception cause says argument "type" mismatch. I also updated the question with this detail..

Comment: Change `TestBean.value` to an integer and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The transform of the result query can be explicitly set each parameter to the corresponding model datatype using hibernate addScalar() method. Please find the solution below.

```
    Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().createSQLQuery(""+
                "select " +
                " exists(select * from A where id = 3) as value"
                ).addScalar("value",  BooleanType.INSTANCE);
```

This will resolve to set to the Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old answer, I tried to resolve this coz answer from here not worked for me.

with Addition to Answer from @anil bk, I overloaded a setter method accepting  `String` as argument. Now It worked as expected.

```
public void setPriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = "true".equals(priority);
}
```

Here is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48125255/3425489)