# IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch in Hibernate while using AliasToBeanResultTransformer and MySQL UNION SQLQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I used `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` in Hibernate for following query and It **works**
**SQL Query 1**

```
//Query 1
final String GET_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS = 
    "select distinct wtd.work_task_detail_id as workTaskDetailId, wtd.assigned_task as assignedTask, "
    + "e.emp_id as employeeId, concat( e.first_name,' ',e.last_name ) as employeeName, "
    + "wtd.deadline_date as deadlineDate, a.code_name as workTaskStatusName, a.code_id as workTaskStatusId, "
    + "wtd.completion_date as completionDate, wtd.priority as priority "
    + "from work_task_detail wtd "
    + "join allcode a on a.code_id = wtd.work_task_status "
    + "join employee e on e.emp_id = wtd.team_member_id  "
    + "where wtd.work_task_detail_id = :assignmentId";
```

If I used same selection criteria in MySQL **union** query it gives me exception **IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch**

**SQL Query 2**

```
//Query 2           
final String GET_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS = 
    "select distinct wtd.work_task_detail_id as workTaskDetailId, wtd.assigned_task as assignedTask, "
    + "e.emp_id as employeeId, concat( e.first_name,' ',e.last_name ) as employeeName, "
    + "wtd.deadline_date as deadlineDate, a.code_name as workTaskStatusName, a.code_id as workTaskStatusId, "
    + "wtd.completion_date as completionDate, wtd.priority as priority "
    + "from work_task_detail wtd "
    + "join logs l on wtd.work_task_detail_id = l.tran_id and l.transaction='ASGNMT' "
    + "join user u on u.user_id = l.user_id "
    + "join employee e on e.emp_id = u.emp_id "
    + "join allcode a on a.code_id = wtd.work_task_status "
    + "where wtd.work_task_detail_id = :assignmentId and l.user_id = :userId "
    + "union "
    + "select distinct wtd.work_task_detail_id as workTaskDetailId, wtd.assigned_task as assignedTask, "
    + "e.emp_id as employeeId, concat( e.first_name,' ',e.last_name ) as employeeName, "
    + "wtd.deadline_date as deadlineDate, a.code_name as workTaskStatusName, a.code_id as workTaskStatusId, "
    + "wtd.completion_date as completionDate, wtd.priority as priority "
    + "from work_task_detail wtd "
    + "join allcode a on a.code_id = wtd.work_task_status "
    + "join employee e on e.emp_id = wtd.team_member_id  "
    + "where wtd.work_task_detail_id = :assignmentId and wtd.team_member_id = ( select emp_id from user uu where uu.user_id = :userId )";
```

Why using **UNION** resulting in following exception ?
**LOG**

```
05-01-2018 12:14:57 320 org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:97) 
 HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: support.dto.AssignmentStatus, setter method of property: priority 
 05-01-2018 12:14:57 324 org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:98) 
 HHH000091: Expected type: boolean, actual value: java.lang.Byte
```

**Another One**

```
05-01-2018 12:14:57 342 support.DAO.ImplDeveloperDAO.getAssignmentStatus(ImplDeveloperDAO.java:1916) 
 Message     :- IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [support.dto.AssignmentStatus.priority (expected type = boolean)]; target = [support.dto.AssignmentStatus@11643c8], property value = [0] setter of support.dto.AssignmentStatus.priority 
 05-01-2018 12:14:57 345 support.DAO.ImplDeveloperDAO.getAssignmentStatus(ImplDeveloperDAO.java:1917) 
 Root Cause  :- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch 
 05-01-2018 12:14:57 346 support.DAO.ImplDeveloperDAO.getAssignmentStatus(ImplDeveloperDAO.java:1918) 
              ************************************************************
```

what I tried so far

1. I used **if( wtd.priority = 0, FALSE, TRUE )** in selection criteria
2. I also tried two more overloaded setters for `priority` one with parameter as `byte` and other with `BigInteger`

Comment: I can see there are few differences in those two queries like you are using userId parameter in the second query and one side of the union is using the subquery. As there are these differences in the query structure, we can't say its due to the Union only. Have you checked about those differences?

Comment: I know these diferences, I will check again and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44963213/3425489) still getting problem, with suggestion
`Expected type: boolean, actual value: java.lang.String`

so I overloaded a setter method for my field `priority` acceptiong `String` as argument. Now It worked as expected.

```
public void setPriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = "true".equals(priority);
}
```

Thank you.